# Ajax- beforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In order to prevent getting an error twice I use beforeSend.

```
hasSent = false

function submit() {
    if (!hasSent)
        $.ajax({
            url: "${createLink(controller:'userInvitation', action:'ajaxUpdate')}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#invitationForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#invitationForm')[0].reset();
                $('.thank-you-modal').modal('show');
                hasSent = true;
                console.log(hasSent)
            },

            complete: function() {
                hasSent = false;
                console.log(hasSent)
            }
        });
}
```

As you can see the ajax should happen only if `hasSent=false`.
For some reason the `ajax` happens also if the user clicks multiple time (very quick) on the submit button

Comment: `hasSent` doesn't update to true until you get a response back from the call, so clicking it twice means it might just fire again before your response comes back.

It might be prudent to update it at the start of the function after the if statement, and then make it false once you complete.

Comment: You could disable the button onclick.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this kind of issue disable the button before sending the ajax and then anable inside the success function

```
$(mybutton).prop("disabled",true);
// ajax call here
```

then

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $(mybutton).prop("disabled",false);
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another flag such as **isSending**

```
function submit() {
   if(isSending)
     return;

   isSending = true

   $.ajax({
       // ...
        complete: function() {
            isSending = false;
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can do this.

1) create a flag and check if the button is pressed. If pressed then do not execute the ajax code

change the flag back once the request is successful, like this

```
   success:function(...)
            {
               flag=false;
            }
```

Or you can disable the button at the button click so the request will be carried out and double click situation won't arise. Enable the button on complete like this

```
 complete:function(..){ $("yourbutton").attr("disabled",false)}
```